# What script for storing/passing value from html page1 to page2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making a listview and I want to pass some value such as "name", "info", "hap", "lat" and "lon" to page2.html. What is the correct or best way to do it? In php, I use POST or GET is there some better way to do it?  If GET is the way to go, how to implement it in page2? Yes, I am googled still unsure how to do it correctly.

```
<div data-role="page" id="manual">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Manual</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="directory" data-role="listview" data-inset="false"
            data-filter="true">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


function parseXML(xml) {
    $(xml).find("cat").each(
            function() {
                name = $(this).attr("name");
                info = $(this).attr("info");
                hap = $(this).attr("hap");
                lat = $(this).attr("lat");
                lon = $(this).attr("lon");
                code = $(this).attr("code");
                $("#directory").append(
                        "<li><a href=\"page2.html?name=\"" + name + ">" + name + "</a></li>");
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `localStorage`. You can store key/value pairs locally using JavaScript, and it's really simple:

```
// Setting a value
localStorage.setItem("someKey", "some value");

// Getting a value
var someValue = localStorage.getItem("someKey");
```

The values are also saved across pages and sessions.

For more information, see the [description in the Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html).

Comment: I did tried onClick method and assign value using localStorage.id="test". I cannot retrieve "test" but if I put "123" I can retrieve it. Why it only work on numeric?

Comment: You have to use localStorage.setItem, not localStorage.id! See this jsFiddle, it works perfectly with all kinds of keys: http://jsfiddle.net/bRCfs/

Comment: Thanks, how do I add it as onClick?
$("#directory").append("<li><a href=\"page2.html?code=test\" onclick=\"localStorage.setItem(\"name\", \"Test\");\")>" + name + "</a></li>");});

Comment: See here for information about [JavaScript's onclick property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick). Or here for [jQuery's click() function](http://api.jquery.com/click/). (Also, if you like my answer, please click on "Accept answer". Thanks!)

Comment: Thanks, I manage to get it working with localStorage. Cheers.

Comment: No problem. Please select my answer as the solution for your problem by clicking the tick on the left hand-side of my answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
(function(){  
    var get = window.$_GET = {};  
    var args = location.search.replace('?','').split('&');  
    for(var i=0,j=args.length,temp;i<j;i++){  
        temp = args[i].split('=');  
        get[temp[0]] = temp[1];  
    }  
})();  

// test
if(!$_GET['arg1'])location.href = "?arg1=111&arg2=4545454545";  
for(var p in $_GET){  
    alert('The argument'+p+'\'s value is：'+$_GET[p]+'<br>');  
} 
</script>
```

I don't know if you can understand.Wish to help you.

Comment: Thanks Andy, is there a longer or more complete code about the above?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very good at using English. I try to describe clearly.You can copy the code before comment and paste into the script tag,then you can use $_GET['name'] to get the value of 'name';

Comment: 普通话也可以。 Is it something like this?   

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){  
      var get = window.$_GET = {};  
      var args = location.search.replace('?','').split('&');  
      for(var i=0,j=args.length,temp;i<j;i++){  
          temp = args[i].split('=');  
          get[temp[0]] = temp[1];  
      }  
  })(); 
  

  $("#mallheader").append("<h1>"+$_GET['mallname']+"</h1>");
  </script>

But I can't get it work.

Comment: page2.html?mallname=123456 then test.But why not visit http://bbs.blueidea.com or http://bbs.csdn.net ?